# How to display two columns into one column with two lines?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have some problem with my database query:

```
SELECT 
    a.survey_id,
    c.questions_first_language ||'-'|| c.questions_second_language as statements,
FROM survey a
    LEFT JOIN survey_questions b
        on a.survey_id = b.survey_id
```

How the column "statements" looks like this:

```
 ============================
 statements
 ============================
 | questions_first_language |
 | questions_second_language|
 |__________________________|
 | questions_third_language |
 | questions_fourth_language|
 |                          |
 ============================
```

Comment: Left justified SQL is too hard to read...

Comment: just change `||'-'||` to `||chr(10)||`

Comment: I am using postgresql @Shadow

Comment: @BrianYudhanto yes it does.

Comment: Is working! :), I'm sorry my box columns is too small, so the second value is not visible @VaoTsun

Comment: :) that is funny.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just in two lines? this?

```
SELECT 
a.survey_id,
c.questions_first_language ||chr(10)|| c.questions_second_language as statements,
FROM survey a
LEFT JOIN survey_questions b
on a.survey_id = b.survey_id
```